# What is the right way to use Internet Sharing in OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, iphone

For a while now I've been using the Wireless in my Mac Mini as a seperate WiFi access point because my main router doesn't quite cover my whole house. There is a dedicated CAT 5E line down to the Mini, which has a static IP address.

I've turned Internet Sharing on, using Airport/WiFi but it seems my options for security are limited. Can I do WPA2? Also, it seems like my iPhone only connects 25% of the time, and the rest of the time it claims I've given a bad password. I've tried "Forget this network" repeatedly.

Comment: No WPA2, just WEP. See "How to troubleshoot problems sharing internet connection via WiFi on Mac OS X" at http://superuser.com/questions/71320/how-to-troubleshoot-problems-sharing-internet-connection-via-wifi-on-mac-os-x (and "How To Share The Internet Connection Between Mac and PC" at http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-share-the-internet-connection-between-your-mac-and-a-pc/#comment-419551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also run into this problem when using Internet Sharing in OS X. It seems that Internet Sharing is only setup to work for impromptu mac-to-mac networks, especially when not using Mac OS X Server.

You might have better luck buying a [cheap wireless router](http://www.google.com/products?q=wireless%20router&scoring=p), disabling NAT, and using it as a wireless bridge.